# How to propagate $data inside all parts of a view?

Tags: codeigniter, frameworks, view, codeigniter-3

I need to propagate all controller `$data` inside all parts of a view (header, top, sidebar-left, sidebar-right, footer) and as I do not know the correct method of performing this task, I'm sending `$data` to all parts that build this view.

```
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {

    public function loader_page($views, $data = null){

        $this->view("incs/header",              $data);
        $this->view("incs/top",                 $data);
        $this->view("incs/sidebar-left",        $data);
        $this->view("incs/system_messages",     $data);
        $this->view($views,                     $data);
        $this->view("incs/sidebar-right",       $data);
        $this->view("incs/footer",              $data);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know the correct way to perform this task without sending `$data` in all parts that build the view?

[image]

Comment: What don't you like about the current way you are doing things? Is it not working? And why are you overriding/adding a loader function? Just make a template model or something to do this. No need to extend the loader class.

Comment: The only other way I could see getting `$data` to every view without having to do it this way would involve modifications to the core  - it wouldn't improve anything, and I don't see anything wrong with the way you are doing things (aside from maybe moving this to a model).

Answer (score 2):

You should extend from `MY_Controller` try this .

in `application/core/MY_Controller.php`

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{

    public function loader_page($views, $data = []){

       $this->load->view("incs/header",              $data);
       $this->load->view("incs/top",                 $data);
       $this->load->view("incs/sidebar-left",        $data);
       $this->load->view("incs/system_messages",     $data);
       $this->load->view($views,                     $data);
       $this->load->view("incs/sidebar-right",       $data);
       $this->load->view("incs/footer",              $data);

    }

}
```

in your controller

```
class Inicio extends MY_Controller{

   public function __construct(){
       parent::__construct();
   }

   public function index() {
       $data['title'] = 'Your title';
       $this->loader_page('forms', $data);
   }

}
```

hope this helps